# Remove elements of an array from another array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
a[] = [1,2,3,4]
b[] = [1,4]
```

Need to remove elements of array b from array a.

Expected output:

```
 a[] = [1,4]
```

Comment: Do you mean b[] = [2,3] ?
To have what you expected as a[] = [1,4].

Answer (score 16):

I would use the filter method:

```
a = a.filter(function (item) {
    return b.indexOf(item) === -1;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: return b.indexOf(item) == -1;

Comment: @Kolby thanks for the correction. The closing parentheses must be after item and the comparson operator should be === instead of !==

Answer (score 4):

```
const array_diff = (a, b) => a.filter(v => !b.includes(v))
```

If you want to support IE

```
const array_diff = (a, b) => a.filter(v => b.indexOf(v) === -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm looping over the second array, and checking if the value is in the first array using `indexOf` If it is I use `splice` to remove it.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [3,4,5];

b.forEach(function(val){
  var foundIndex = a.indexOf(val);
  if(foundIndex != -1){
    a.splice(foundIndex, 1);
  }
});
```

Or

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [3,4,5];

a = a.filter(x => b.indexOf(x) == -1);
```

For IE 8,

```
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
   var val = b[i];
   var foundIndex = a.indexOf(val);
   if(foundIndex != -1){
      a.splice(foundIndex, 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: array.prototype.forEach - new in ECMAScript5 (ie not <=IE8): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @freedomn-m is right .forEach is ECMAScript5 so you either need to transpile, use a library that has a forEach method, or just use a for loop. The logic remains the same.

Comment: For IE 8,

for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
   var val = b[i];
   var foundIndex = a.indexOf(val);
   if(foundIndex != -1){
      a.splice(foundIndex, 1);
   }
}

Comment: Added IE8. Thanks @Aruna

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the jQuery docs for [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) and [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Here's what the code would look like:

```
var first = [1,2,3,4],
    second = [3,4];

var firstExcludeSecond = $.grep(first, function(ele, ix){ return $.inArray(ele, second) === -1; });

console.log(firstExcludeSecond);
```

Basically amounts to iterating through the first array ($.grep) and determining if a given value is in the second array ($.inArray).  If the value returned from $.inArray is -1, the value from the first array does not exist in the second so we grab it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a.filter(item => b.indexOf(item) < 0)
}

console.log(myFunction([1, 2, 3], [1, 2]))
```